# How do I get the current values of the gyro?

Tags: gyroscope, unityscript, oculus

Im new to Unity and just started to do some experminets with the oculus to play around some and hopefully gain some knowledge along the way..
however.. I dont get how to get the x,y,z (and w?) values of the gyro..or any value at all from the actuall gyro.. in my case the camera-rotation cant be used since I need the "default" orientation option to be disabled since I want to create my own custom behavior for the camera.

Br,
Inx

Comment: wasnt that hard after some research in the integration scripts of OVR for unity... hopefully this will help someone:
Quaternion rot = new Quaternion();
  
  OVRDevice.GetOrientation(0, ref rot);

Answer (score 2):

You need to first enable the gyroscope before you can get values from it.

```
Input.gyro.enable = true; //Preferably in the Start() function.
```

You should now be able to read values for example for user acceleration along x, use

```
float userAccel = Input.gyro.userAcceleration.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before reading the values enable gyroscope ( For example in Start() method ).

Use

```
Input.gyro.enable = true;
```